# Drop down box and its elements using buttons which contains an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function populateWidgets(dashboardname){

$("#widgets").empty();
var widgets=dashboard[dashboardname];
for(var i=0; i< widgets.length ; i++){
$("#widgets").append('<li><button class="widgetbutton"><span><font color="blue"><font size=2px><b>'+widgets[i]+'</b></font></font></span></button></li>');
}
function buttonOnclick(e){
console.log();
var new_dashboard={
dashboard_selected: dashboardname,
widget_selected: e.currentTarget.innerText
}
postdata(new_dashboard); 
}
$('button').click(buttonOnclick);
}
function postdata(new_dashboard){
$.post( "/geckoapi", new_dashboard).done(function(dashboardname) {
alert( "Dashboard and Widget Loaded: " + dashboardname);
});
}
```

This is portion in my code which used to make alert box containing the clicked dashboard and widget.
I want to know that on alert button we are only giving dashboard name(function) but on alert box we get dashboard name as well as widget name. how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how it works,**

This statement returns the widgets of the selected dashboard.

```
var widgets=dashboard[dashboardname];
```

Here we add the button, which contains the widget name.

```
$("#widgets").append('<li><button class="widgetbutton"><span><font color="blue"><font size=2px><b>'+ widgets[i] +'</b></font></font></span></button></li>');
```

In the below event handler, we get the dashboard name , which is the parameter in the populateWidgets function and widget name, which is in the button itself that was clicked.

```
function buttonOnclick(e){
  console.log();
  var new_dashboard={
    dashboard_selected: dashboardname,
    widget_selected: e.currentTarget.innerText
  }
  postdata(new_dashboard); 
}
```